# Passing array from php to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I know this question has several different answers already, but I've tried every single approach, and still not making progress. I am trying to pass an array to ajax, but ajax treats the response data as a string.

Here is my php code:

```
$code = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bragcode']);

$re_query = "SELECT * FROM reordertbl WHERE reordercode = '$code'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$re_query);
$rowSelected   = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if ($rowSelected) {
   $id = $rowSelected["orderId"];
   $data = "SELECT bragName, bragTitle, groupUUID FROM ordertbl WHERE orderId = '$id'";
   $dataresult = mysqli_query($con,$data);
   $dataSelected   = mysqli_fetch_array($dataresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $response = array("1", $dataSelected["bragName"], $dataSelected["bragTitle"], $dataSelected["groupUUID"]);

   }else {

   $response = 0;
}

echo json_encode($response);


mysqli_close($con);
```

Am passing the $response array to ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'searchBrag.php',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: bragdata,
        datatype: 'json',
        encode: true,
        success: function (data){
                    var m = data[0];
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(m);
                 }
})
```

My console log gives this output:

**console.log(data) returns correct data -** 
["1","My Trip to Vegas","What happens in vega","a6fa55c1-da29-400b-9ce9-646e58dd5ed6~2"]

**console.log(m)  returns first bracket which is not the expectation -** [

Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: It's `dataType`, not `datatype`.

Comment: +1 for using mysqli, -1 for not using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: `header("Content-Type: application/json");` always helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your jquery ajax call, "datatype" should be "dataType" (case sensitive).

At the moment your jquery is treating the response as a string, which is why m[0] is resulting in a [ character (since the string begins with that character).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

SO:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'searchBrag.php',
        type: 'POST', 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: bragdata,
        datatype: 'json',
        encode: true,
        success: function (data){
                    var m = data[0];
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(m);
                 }
})
```